# Why Multiple Where Clause not Woking in nativeQuery

Tags: sql, spring-data-jpa, mariadb, nativequery, hibernate-native-query

```
 @Query(
      nativeQuery = true,
      value =
          "SELECT td.trip_date, td.trip_code, td.trip_distance, td.trip_travel_time, tu.status, tu.pickup_drop_time, u.id, u.user_name\n"
              + "FROM trip_details td  JOIN trip_users tu ON tu.trip_details_trip_id=td.trip_id \n"
              + "JOIN users u ON u.id=tu.trip_user_id \n"
              + "WHERE td.trip_date BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate \n"
              + "AND u.id =: userId")
  List<Object> getMobileForUpComingTripDetails(
      @Param("userId") Integer userId,
      @Param("fromDate") Date fromDate,
      @Param("toDate") Date toDate);
```

IT will gives error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for method public abstract java.util.List com.dao.interfaces.TripDetailsDao.
getMobileForUpComingTripDetails(java.lang.Integer,java.util.Date,java.util.Date) but parameter 'userId' not found in annotated query 'SELECT td.trip_date, td.trip_code, td.trip_distance, td.trip_travel_time, tu.status, tu.pickup_drop_time, u.id, u.user_name
FROM trip_details td  JOIN trip_users tu ON tu.trip_details_trip_id=td.trip_id 
JOIN users u ON u.id=tu.trip_user_id 
WHERE td.trip_date BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate 
AND tu.trip_user_id = : userId'!
```

But when we use single where clause its working

```
 @Query(
      nativeQuery = true,
      value =
          "SELECT td.trip_date, td.trip_code, td.trip_distance, td.trip_travel_time, tu.status, tu.pickup_drop_time, u.id, u.user_name\n"
              + "FROM trip_details td  JOIN trip_users tu ON tu.trip_details_trip_id=td.trip_id \n"
              + "JOIN users u ON u.id=tu.trip_user_id \n"
              + "WHERE td.trip_date BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate")
  List<Object> getMobileForUpComingTripDetails(
     // @Param("userId") Integer userId,
      @Param("fromDate") Date fromDate,
      @Param("toDate") Date toDate);
```

and my response is

```
[
   {
        "tripDate": "15/02/2022",
        "tripCode": "2sdfsdfklsfj0001",
        "userName": "jkl.com",
        "userId": 204
    },
    {
        "tripDate": "15/02/2022",
        "tripCode": "220xsdjffksf0001",
        "userName": "abc.com",
        "userId": 210
    },
]
```

But my problem is based on queryParm as userId we get data not all, so i added multiple where claues we get error please help me for that.

Comment: I don't know this language, but it looks like a mis-placed space `=: userId` here

Comment: ***Include the error message***, stack trace, etc, in your question!

Comment: @HoneyBadger  where i  miss-place =: userId in query

Comment: `=: userId` looks like it should be `= :userId`

Comment: I also think `=: userId` is the problem. but remember to also include the error message for your further question.

Comment: @sajjadrezaei added error msg

Comment: Your question has `AND u.id =: userId`, your error message has `AND tu.trip_user_id = : userId` *(so your question appears to **not** include the exact code that actually generated that error message)*.  It should be `= :userId`.  Spaces and attention to details matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So AS you look at the error message it obviously said that the parameter `userId` was not found in the query. It's because of your typo in the query:

`+ "AND u.id =: userId")`

it should be  like:

`+ "AND u.id = :userId")`

Reading the error message always helps you with debugging.